# Does Perl 6's eof give up too quickly?

Tags: raku, filehandle

In Perl 5 I can check if standard input is open and read one line from it.

```
for (;;) {
    last if eof(STDIN);
    print "Got line " . readline(STDIN);
    }
```

When I run it an enter a line of input it reads that line and does its work before moving on. The program does not care if there are long pauses:

```
$ perl print-stdin.pl
this
Got line this
is
Got line is
a
Got line a
line
Got line line
```

If I do the same thing in Perl 6 (Rakudo 2017.07) the program stops right away:

```
use v6;
loop {
    last if $*IN.eof;
    put "Got line " ~ $*IN.get;
    }
```

I'm really after a `Supply` that can give me one line of input as it arrives (perhaps from a program that slowly outputs line with long pauses) but I backed up all the way to this simple problem. I didn't find a builtin way to do this (which is a bit surprising for such a common task).

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work better on latest.
Although what you wrote has a race condition as the input can be closed after the call to `.eof`. Which means it can happen while `.get` is blocked, so it will return `Nil`. This would cause a warning to be thrown, and an extra `Got line`  to be printed.

It's better to just use the Iterator from `.lines`

```perl6
for $*IN.lines { put "Got line $_" }
```

or use the return value of `.get` to determine when the input is closed.

```perl6
loop {
  with $*IN.get {
    put "Got line $_"
  } else {
    last
  }
}
```

---

If you want a Supply from the input lines:

```perl6
$*IN.lines.Supply
```

```perl6
react {
  start whenever $*IN.lines.Supply {
    put "Got line $_";
    LAST done; # finish the outer ｢react｣ block when this closes
  }
  whenever Supply.interval(1) {
    put DateTime.now.hh-mm-ss
  }
}
```

```
22:46:33
22:46:34
a
Got line a
22:46:35
22:46:36
b
Got line b
22:46:37
22:46:38
c
Got line c
22:46:39
22:46:40
d
Got line d
22:46:41
22:46:42
^D               # represents Ctrl+D
```

The `start` is needed above so it doesn't block the `Supply.interval(1)` supply from starting properly.

---

If the above wasn't possible for some reason you could create a Supply like this:

```perl6
my \in-supply = supply {

  # ｢await start｣ needed so this won't block other things on this thread.

  await start loop {
    with $*IN.get { # defined (so still open)

      emit $_

    } else {        # not defined (closed)

      done;         # stop the Supply

      # last        # stop this loop (never reached)

    }
  }
}

react {
  whenever in-supply {
    put "Got line $_";
    LAST done # finish the outer ｢react｣ block when this closes
  }
  whenever Supply.interval(1) {
    put DateTime.now.hh-mm-ss
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd still like to know what's going on with `eof`.

Comment: @briandfoy `.eof` returns True if the input is at the end of the file at the exact moment `.eof` is called (non-blocking). There is no way to know if the eof is reached on a TTY until it is closed. `.get` blocks until `\r` `\r\n` `\n` etc or the end of the file. Which means a TTY is more likely to get closed during the call to `.get` than the millisecond between calls to `.get`. Basically don't use `.eof` in the way you are using it. (I learned this using Perl 5 at least 5 years ago, even though it is less of a problem there)

Comment: Yes, for a TTY I'd expect eof to not return True until the TTY is closed.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and there's no race condition. `.eof` won't return `False` until both the input file handle has been exhausted and the decoder buffer has been exhausted.

Comment: @BradGilbert the `Nil` you observed was due to [a now-fixed bug in MoarVM](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/commit/2f0672f74523c6ddfe8a216728bbbea8fc7760ce)

Comment: @ZoffixZnet That actually breaks it in a new way. Instead of possibly not returning True at the end of file, it returns True at the end of a line if you are using an interactive TTY. The only way to fix it so that it works more like Perl 5's `eof` is to make it block (probably not a good idea).